# mp4box's mp4 seek is slower than input h264

Tags: video, h.264, mp4

I have an h264 file generated from a TI DM365 processor.  When I play it in VLC player, I am able to jump to any part of the video and it will play quickly.  However, when I use mp4box to put the h264 into an mp4 file, trying to jump to the end of a 40 minute file can take 4 minutes.  It seems like it's dropping key frames.  Are there settings I can use that will keep the seek performance fast. Note: I used ffmpeg to do the conversion and it took 10 minutes to convert, but seeks fast.  mp4box converts fast and seeks slow.

Answer (score 1):

Just speculation, but I would guess that the TI is including key frames only very sparsely.

When you do the conversion with FFmpeg, it re-encodes the file, adding keyframes at reasonable intervals.  Thus, conversion is slow, but seeking is fast.  With mp4box, no re-encoding is done so conversion goes quickly, but seeking takes forever because keyframes are few and far between.

The solution is to either do the re-encoding and accept that it will take some time but allow fast seeking, or just repackage the stream and get fast conversion at the cost of slow seeking.